# Masonry and Bootstrap 3 - 3 columns of different sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've been fighting with Bootstrap and Masonry for over 3-4 hours now and searched tons of articles but couldn't find the solution.

Here's the thing:

I have Bootstrap Grid that looks like this:

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="col-md-6 item"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
</div>
```

In total there are 12 columns and without Masonry it works just perfect.
But as soon as I include Masonry, the third column drops down.

If I make it 6-6 columns or 4-4-4 columns and 3-3-3-3 they work fine, but 6-3-3 doesn't work.

Does anyone have a solution for it? Any ideas how to have this cool layout? Do I have to implement my fluid grid? Why does Masonry break with Bootstrap?

This is a JS fiddle to illustrate https://jsfiddle.net/bePolite/52VtD/11921/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

need to include an `<div class="row">` will work, like you want...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="itemsContainer">
        <div class="col-md-6 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gonna try it and let you know. I don't remember exactly but I think I tried that too.

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't work, I even added 2 div class="row" but still nothing. It just can't fit third column. Though there's a lot of space. Thanks anyway for your time and advice!

Comment: i have this -> http://prntscr.com/79m8i5

i'll changed for you see it works...

http://prntscr.com/79m8wt

Comment: Now I see that you didn't catch up with my question. Bootstrap itself works the way it's intended even without DIV CLASS="ROW", but it's MASONRY.JS that I want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

[bootstrap Grid Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/dhfs7v14/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Divs with same col's</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 bg1"><p class="lead"> i'm div col-xs-4 </p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 bg2"><p class="lead"> i'm div col-xs-4 </p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 bg3"><p class="lead"> i'm div col-xs-4 </p></div>
    </div>
    <h1>Divs with differents col's</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 bg1"><p class="lead"> i'm div col-xs-6 </p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg2"><p class="lead"> i'm div col-xs-3 </p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg3"><p class="lead"> i'm div col-xs-3 </p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this will show you like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, only Bootstrap will align the way I want it, but in this example you use only bootstrap without Masonry.js or Shuffle.js or anything. If you take a look at my question you'll see that I'm trying to implement Masonry.js

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time!