# Masonry not working with different width columns of bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

Masonry works fine with same width columns (3-3-3-3, 4-4-4, 6-6 etc).
But not working (layout breaks ) with different width columns (8-4, 9-3 etc).

Please see the screenshot. I am trying to achieve this http://prntscr.com/8bu4lr layout.

The markup:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="masonry-container row"> 
    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="masonry-item  col-xs-12 col-sm-8"> 
    </div><!-- /.masonry-item -->                       

    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="masonry-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 "> 
    </div><!-- /.masonry-item -->   

    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="masonry-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 "> 
    </div><!-- /.masonry-item -->       


</div><!-- /.row -->
```

```
//init masonry
$('.masonry-container').masonry({
  // options
  columnWidth: '.masonry-item',
  itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
});
```

Another person asked about the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439564/masonry-and-bootstrap-3-3-columns-of-different-sizes)

Answer (score 2):

From what I've found when working with Bootstrap and Masonry is that Masonry doesn't appear to like Bootstrap's grid system. I could not get it to work at all with their grid so I decided to strip it down to the absolute basics, including just the width. Then it worked perfectly fine for me even with different sized columns.

This is my stripped down grid system for use with Masonry:

```
$breakpoints: (xs, sm, md, lg);
$calculation: '';

@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {

  @for $i from 1 through 12 {

    $calculation: 0% + ($i * 100 / 12);

    .masonry-#{$breakpoint}-#{$i} {

      @if $breakpoint == 'xs' {
        width: $calculation;
      }
      @else if $breakpoint == 'sm' {

        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
          width: $calculation;  
        }
      }
      @else if $breakpoint == 'md' {

        @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
          width: $calculation;  
        }
      }
      @else if $breakpoint == 'lg' {

        @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
          width: $calculation;  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should you however not be using sass you can easily use this online converter to get the outputted CSS right away:

http://sassmeister.com/

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code... this problem with Bootstrap 3 grid with masonry gutter being anything but 0 was driving me mad for ages - my three column layout kept dropping to two columns with gutter on. I did have to modify your code to fix it by changing all the "width: $calculation;" lines to "width: calc(#{$calculation} - 10px);" where 10px is what I have the masonry gutter set to "gutter: 10".